# MySql - How to select the row a warning occurred at?

Tags: mysql, warnings, alter

While running an `ALTER TABLE` statement, I got these warnings back:

[image]

How do I  `SELECT` from my table `at row 3522` to see what went wrong?

I'm not sure if `row` refers to the primary key or what?

I tried something like this:

`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 3521,1; // for row 3522`

Comment: Your query looks like fine, what's your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to measure length of 'date_due_lastupdated' and 'date_completion_lastupdated' with your SQL? At these specific rows data length in these fields should be the same size as column max lenght.

Warnings are related to primary key - your query is ok.

You can create table with varchar(7) - fill it with data (5-7 char lenght) and then alter column varchar(6).